# How to get the value at the latest date, where values are not null?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like this. Notice the blank values towards the bottom.

[image]

I would like to get the value of the latest date, but the value can't be null.

My DAX formula is bringing back the value of the latest date (`19/12/2021`) which is `null`however I want to bring back the latest non-null value, which is for the date `21/11/2021`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Latest Value = 
CALCULATE(
    // get sum of value column
    SUM('Table1'[Value]), 
    // where value is not blank, and date is max date
    'Table1'[Value] <> BLANK() && Table1[Date] = MAX(Table1[Date])
)
```

I thought this should bring back the figure 305? Because my conditions are:

`where value is not null AND where date = max date`

Shouldn't the max date now be `21/11/21` because the nulls have been removed?

Another piece of DAX I've tried, using the `fiter` function.

```
Latest Value = CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table1'[Value]),
    FILTER(ALL('Table1'),
    'Table1'[Value] <> BLANK()
    &&
    'Table1'[Date] = MAX('Table1'[Date]))
```

Where am I going wrong? I think it's something to do with my `max date` section.

Unfortunately all file hosters are blocked in work, so I can't share this dummy file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to filter the table first and get the max value from the date column. In my case, I saved that date in a variable last_date. Then we just select a value from the Value column using filter by last_date.

```
LatestValue =
VAR last_date =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table1'[Date] ), 'Table1'[Value] <> BLANK () )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table1'[Value] ), 'Table1'[Date] = last_date )
```

or the same expression with SUM:

```
LatestSumOfValues = 
VAR last_date = CALCULATE(MAX('Table1'[Date]),'Table1'[Value] <> BLANK())
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM('Table1'[Value]),'Table1'[Date] = last_date)
```

Comment: That works, thank you